# Simple Query via JDBCTemplate very slow

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Hey i have the following query which i am executing via an autowired jdbctemplate in my spring-boot application:

```
query = "select fromfilepath from filecopyeventlog where copytype = 1 ORDER BY copytimestamp DESC LIMIT 1"
```

i execute the query via:

```
String result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, String.class);
```

since the result is just a single column defined as varchar(250).

Now the problem is, that this query is very slow when executed in my application - it takes many minutes.. 
when i execute the query direcly on the database webinterface (h2), i get the result in less then 900ms.

does someone have any idea? The result looks like:

```
/data/internal/s3/sensor-data/semiconductor_2019-07-12T01_17_11Z.mf4.gz
```

in the database are more then 500.000 rows.

I think the query is fine it seems like something in the result mapping? I thought maybe the backslashes are bad and changed them, to "_" but that resulted in no change.

hope someone can help :)